# Airflow on_success callback function failing with "Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses"

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Our on_success callback function is being killed abortly by airflow before completion. But the airflow task is marked as success. 
Our on_success callback function is a simple python function with no multithreading. I've replicated the same error by replacing our actual logic with sleep(10).
Please refer the below code to recreate the issue.

If I reduce the sleep time to 2 then it completes successfuly. If my on_success function takes more than 2 seconds then airflow kills it abortly.

Anyone help is appreciated.

Airflow version: v1.10.0

code:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='testing_on_success',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    concurrency=5,
    catchup=True)


def notify_success(context):
    print("inside notify_success")
    time.sleep(10) #actual logic execution time is represented by sleeping to 10 seconds 
    print("sleeping done")
    return


def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    time.sleep(10)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    on_success_callback=notify_success,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Log:

```
[2019-12-11 18:32:23,826] {base_task_runner.py:107} INFO - Job 75401: Subtask run_this [2019-12-11 18:32:23,825] {cli.py:492} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: testing_on_success.run_this 2019-06-14T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host xyz
[2019-12-11 18:32:23,933] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - {'dag': <DAG: testing_on_success>, 'next_ds': '2019-06-14', 'prev_ds': '2019-06-13', 'ds_nodash': '20190614', 'ts': '2019-06-14T00:00:00+00:00', 'etc..'}

[2019-12-11 18:32:23,933] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - 2019-06-14

[2019-12-11 18:32:33,943] {python_operator.py:96} INFO - Done. Returned value was: Whatever you return gets printed in the logs
[2019-12-11 18:32:33,995] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - inside notify_success

[2019-12-11 18:32:37,379] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-12-11 18:32:37,379] {jobs.py:2680} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Taking the poison pill.

[2019-12-11 18:32:37,417] {helpers.py:240} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 105969
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,418] {models.py:1610} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,418] {models.py:1689} ERROR - Failed when executing success callback
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,418] {models.py:1690} ERROR - Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1687, in _run_raw_task
    task.on_success_callback(context)
  File "/home/apps/airflow/dags/folder1/testing_on_success.py", line 25, in notify_success
    time.sleep(10) #actual logic execution time is represented by sleeping to 10 seconds
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1612, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,420] {base_task_runner.py:107} INFO - Job 75401: Subtask run_this /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:346: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'PythonOperator' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,420] {base_task_runner.py:107} INFO - Job 75401: Subtask run_this   DeprecationWarning)
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,550] {helpers.py:230} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=105969 (terminated)) (105969) terminated with exit code 0
[2019-12-11 18:32:37,552] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-12-11 18:32:37,551] {jobs.py:2612} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Comment: I know this is old, but did you figure out your issue? I am having the same issue with a different operator

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Am also facing the issue. Thanks